# Dagger Injection into Room Callback - lateinit property has not been initialized error

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am adding a RoomDatabase.Callback() to pre populate my room database on creation.

I am running into an issue of injecting exchangeDao field into my class. When running below i get  error: "lateinit property exchangeDao has not been initialized". This is despite it being called in my line "exchangeDao.insertExchangeList(equityExchange!!)".

How can i run the below code to pre-populate the database?

```
private fun buildDatabase(app: Application) =
    Room.databaseBuilder(
        app,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        "your database name"
    )
        .addCallback(PrePopulateDatabase)
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()
```

> Blockquote

```
object PrePopulateDatabase : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch() {
            val myClass = MyClass()
        }
    }
```

> Blockquote

```
class MyClass {

    @Inject
    lateinit var exchangeDao: ExchangeDao

    init {
            updateExchangeEntity(exchangeDao)
    }

    companion object {

        private fun updateExchangeEntity(
            exchangeDao: ExchangeDao,
        ) {

            var equityExchange: List<ExchangeResponse.Exchange>? = null

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////retrofit object

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.twelvedata.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            val myAPICall = retrofit.create(APICall::class.java)

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////make call

            val call1 = myAPICall.getEquityInstruments("NASDAQ")
            var response1: Response<ExchangeResponse?>? = null
            try {
                response1 = call1!!.execute()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            equityExchange = response1!!.body()!!.data

            exchangeDao.insertExchangeList(equityExchange!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run `MyClass` as a service. This enabled me to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` and use dagger hilt injection. Don't forget to add the new service into the Manifest file.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
 class MyClass: Service() {

@Inject
    lateinit var exchangeDao: ExchangeDao
}
```